# Superstructure of collapsing subspaces

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, soft-question, order-theory, big-list

There seems to be a strange phenomenon occuring in several areas of mathematics.

In group theory, one may quotient away the commutator subgroup to obtain an abelian group.

In the theory of orders, one may collapse equivalence classes (defined by $x \sim y :\Leftrightarrow x \le y \wedge y \le x$) to obtain a (total) order from a (total) preorder.

There are more examples like this: In ring theory for instance, one can divide the nilradical to obtain a ring without nilpotent elements (one can also divide by maximal/prime ideals, but here I don't see how the choice would be unique from the ring).

The phenomenon we observe is this: By collapsing away a canonically defined "unpleasant" subspace (that is one with elements that should not exist in the structure we want), we obtain a "nicer" space (which may contain less information, but may allow (a simplification of) calculations that only rely on the essential structure which is preserved.

My question is this: Are there other places in mathematics where this occurs? Where? How does the construction go?

A further question would be: Is there a category-theoretic interpretation of this phenomenon?

Comment: In topology the [Kolmogorov quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#The_Kolmogorov_quotient) of a non-$T_0$ space is a $T_0$ space that is otherwise ‘just like’ the original space. (This can actually be seen as an instance of the collapse of a preorder to a partial order.) I don’t do category theory, but I believe that many of these examples are instances of [reflective subcategories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory).

Comment: I should also add that there may be a subtle difference between the "algebraic" examples (groups, rings) and the "topology-set theory" examples (top. spaces, preorder): Namely in the latter, all elements have the undesirable property, whereas in the former only some elements have that. And also the constructions are different; in the algebraic case we rely on residue classes.

Comment: These are all examples of the canonical map to a [Reflective subcategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory), which I think is the categorical concept you're after. However not all such maps are quotients. For example, we also have the construction that takes an integral domain an includes it into its field of fractions. (EDIT: I now notice Brian M. Scott already said this.)